# C# .Net Core get current website Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to get Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration object for the current website. Actually, I want to modify the existing settings in web.config but its bit difficult using .net-core I guess. At least if I know the site name then I can get the physical path and modify the web.config using XML API. Can anyone know how to get current website name that my code is running?

I saw Asp.net framework provides

`System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~")
 method`.

It will get the current website configurations. I am looking similar kind of API in .net-core.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue.

I have to use IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath to get the root directory path. Then change the web.config last modified date and time to current time.